# Publishing property changes from polymer element selectively

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I am tying polymer elements in with an existing framework and I am looking for a way to publish events to my framework when certain properties are set on my elements, but only when they are set from a source other then my framework.

For example, I have a custom input element with a "caption" attribute. If data binding inside my elements or some source other than my framework sets the caption property on my control, I want an event published to my framework informing it that the caption property changed, but if my framework sets the caption property, I do not want to publish the event.

I currently publishing these events in an observe block. I have a function on my elements called setFromExternalModel(prop, value) that I use to set the value of a property from my framework. If there were some way for me to pass data from this function on to the observe block, I could prevent the event from being published, but I haven't been able to come up with an elegant way to do this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Why is it important to not fire events if your framework changes a property?
It is much less complicated to treat all property changes the same way.

Polymer's core and paper elements have no concept of framework/user data changes, and we haven't thought of any use cases where this would be important.

Comment: The reason I want to suppress the event is that I don't need to fire it back at the server if it came from the server, especially since it has the potential to overwrite another user's change that may have been committed in between the original property set. I have accomplished my end by using a change log, but I would love to have a functional API to set properties so that I could include metadata that would be forwarded to the event. This would simplify my code.